# $\kappa\psi (x,X)\leq \psi (x,X)$

Tags: general-topology, inequality, cardinals

The $\kappa$-pseudocharacter $\kappa\psi (x,X)$ of a space $X$ at a point
$x\in X$ is the smallest infinite cardinal number $\tau$ such that
there exists a family $\gamma$
 of $\kappa$-sets in $X$ such that
$\{x\} = \bigcap\gamma$.

For every topological group we have following inequality:

> $$\kappa\psi (x,X)\leq \psi (x,X)$$

But how about topological spaces, Is it true for every topological spaces?

---

**Closure of any open set is called $\kappa$-set.**

Comment: It seems for each regular space the inequality holds. Hence the counterexample, if it exists, should be non regular. It is interesting to find a  Hausdorff counterexample, because a $T_1$ non Hausdorff counterxample is trivial: it is every infinite set $X$ endowed with cofinite topology, that is a non empty subset $Y$ of $X$ is open iff $X\backslash Y$ is finite.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: In cofinite topology every open set must contain
all but finitely many points, therefore for each $x\in X$ we have $\psi(x,X)=0+\aleph_0$ and Closure of infinite subset of $X$ is $X$. Hence $\kappa\psi(x,X)=0+\aleph_0$. then $\kappa\psi (x,X)=\psi (x,X)$. Is my argument correct?

Comment: In the cofinite topology on an infinite set $X$ should be $\psi(x)=|X|$ for each point $x\in X$. Since each non-empty $\kappa$-subset of $X$ coincides with $X$, the value of $\kappa\psi(x)$ is undefined, because there is no family $\gamma$ of $\kappa$-sets in $X$ such that $\{x\} = \bigcap\gamma$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Here’s a Hausdorff counterexample. Let $$X=\Big(\omega_1\times(\omega+1)\Big)\cup\{p\}\;,$$ where $p$ is a point not in $\omega_1\times(\omega+1)$. Basic open nbhds of $p$ are the sets

$$B(\alpha,n)=\{p\}\cup\{\langle\xi,k\rangle\in\omega_1\times\omega:\xi>\alpha\text{ and }k\ge n\}$$

for $\langle\alpha,n\rangle\in\omega_1\times\omega$. Clearly $\{p\}=\bigcap_{n\in\omega}B(0,n)$, so $\psi(x,X)=\omega$. Suppose now that $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$. Then $p\in B(\alpha,n)\subseteq U$ for some $\langle\alpha,n\rangle\in\omega_1\times\omega$, and clearly $$(\alpha,\omega_1)\times\{\omega\}\subseteq\cl B(\alpha,n)\subseteq\cl U\;.$$

Let $\{\cl U_k:k\in\omega\}$ be a countable family of $\kappa$-sets containing $p$. For each $k\in\omega$ there is a pair $\langle\alpha_k,n_k\rangle\in\omega_1\times\omega$ such that $B(\alpha_k,n_k)\subseteq U_k$. Let $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_k:k\in\omega\}$; then

$$(\alpha,\omega_1)\times\{\omega\}\subseteq\bigcap_{k\in\omega}\cl B(\alpha_k,n_k)\subseteq\bigcap_{k\in\omega}\cl U_k\;,$$

and it follows that $\kappa\psi(x,X)>\omega$.

Comment: Topology on X is intangible to me. $\omega_1\times(\omega+1)$ has product topology where $ω1=[0,ω1)$ and $ω+1=[0,ω+1)$ have order topology? What is the topology on $X$?

Comment: @TXC: Yes, the ordinal spaces have their order topologies, and $X\setminus\{p\}$ has the product topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Nice example! :-D But it seems there is a small gap in the proof: in the definition of $\kappa\psi (x)$ 
the family $\gamma$ do not necessarily consists of *neighborhoods* of the point $x$. (If it was so, then each space having $\kappa$-pseudocharacter should be Hausdorff. This is why I have deleted my answer. :-) )